# Scanf Won't Scan Struct Inner Data

Tags: c, struct

I need help!

It doesn't matter what I input I get the same output, it's like the program does not read the input from scanf, any ideas?

I tried to get the input separately , to divide the scanf so I will get 8 scanf. 
But with no luck.

If you could help me out and point out on what I have been doing wrong i would appreciate that!

```
 struct point{
  double x;
  double y;
 }pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4;

 struct rect{
      struct point pt1;
      struct point pt2;
      struct point pt3;
      struct point pt4;
 };

  int main()
 {
    struct rect new_screen={
       scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt1.x,&new_screen.pt1.y),
       scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt2.x,&new_screen.pt2.y),
       scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt3.x,&new_screen.pt3.y),
       scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt4.x,&new_screen.pt4.y),
    };
       printf("the middle between (%.2f,%.2f) and (%.2f,%.2f) is ",new_screen.pt1.x,new_screen.pt1.y,new_screen.pt3.x,new_screen.pt3.y);
       print_point(middle(new_screen.pt1,new_screen.pt3));
   return 0;
 }



    struct point middle(struct point pt1, struct point pt2)
    {
        struct point tmp = {((pt1.x+pt2.x)/2),((pt1.y+pt2.y)/2)};
        return tmp;
    }
    void print_point(struct point pt)
    {
        printf("(%.2f,%.2f)",pt.x,pt.y);
    }

     output 
     the middle between (2.00,2.00) and (0.00,0.00) is (1.00,1.00)
```

Comment: You're using the `%f` format to read `double` values.  This is undefined behaviour (`%f` is for `float` types; `%lf` is for `double`).  Modern compilers normally warn you about this; if yours doesn't, find the options to turn the warnings on, or get a better compiler.

Comment: Please always enable warnings in your compiler. For GCC you should add `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`. This will show you a number of warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here initialization...

```
struct rect new_screen = {
   scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt1.x,&new_screen.pt1.y),
   scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt2.x,&new_screen.pt2.y),
   scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt3.x,&new_screen.pt3.y),
   scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt4.x,&new_screen.pt4.y),
};
```

... doesn't do what you think it does. `scanf` returns a single integer (consult its manual page for the meaning of the returned value), but your structure holds `struct point` fields. Which sums up to a total of 8 doubles, and 4 calls to `scanf`. Due to how initialization works in C, you can omit braces and initializers for some fields. So this is sadly valid code. But it initializes `new_screen.pt1` and `new_screen.pt2` only (four calls to `scanf` initialize the four doubles). The thing you scanned into them is immediately overwritten. The last two points aren't initialized by the braces, so they should be initizlied with zeros, again overwriting anything you may have scanned into them.

The long and short of it, is that assuming all `scanf` invocations don't fail (and we ignore the problem with the format specifiers), you essentially wrote this:

```
struct rect new_screen = {
  { 2, 2 },
  { 2, 2 },
  { 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0 }
};
```

The less wrong initialization would be:

```
struct rect new_screen;
scanf("%lf,%lf",&new_screen.pt1.x,&new_screen.pt1.y);
scanf("%lf,%lf",&new_screen.pt2.x,&new_screen.pt2.y);
scanf("%lf,%lf",&new_screen.pt3.x,&new_screen.pt3.y);
scanf("%lf,%lf",&new_screen.pt4.x,&new_screen.pt4.y);
```

It doesn't check that `scanf` succeeded (which is why it's only *less wrong*) but it will not trample the content of `new_screen` with the return value of `scanf`. I also fixed the format specifier (you used `%f`, but `double` variables require `%lf`).

The above mistakes are also a testament to how important it is to compile with warnings enabled, and to address them. For instance, when I compiled your code with `gcc -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` I got these warnings:

```
warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]
    scanf("%f,%f",&new_screen.pt1.x,&new_screen.pt1.y),

warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
    struct rect new_screen={

warning: missing initializer for field 'pt3' of 'struct rect' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
    };
```

Make a habit of compiling with warnings enabled, and address them until the build is free of compiler diagnostics.

Comment: Well spotted on the commas.  I think a novice programmer needs a bit more explanation; it's quite subtle.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Good suggestion. I tried to address it a little more in an edit, hopefully enough to make the point sink with a novice. I don't know how deep to delve into it, so it won't go over a novices head.

Comment: I don't know whether it is too detailed, but I might suggest that the original initializer is equivalent to `struct rect new_screen = { { 2, 2 }, { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };` because the `scanf()` calls return 2 (if the format strings are fixed), and those returned values overwrite the first four elements of the structures, and the other fields are initialized with zeros after the `scanf()` calls have set the values. So the data read from standard input is obliterated by the initialization. I debated whether to write `2.0` instead of `2` in the initializers; laziness left them as integers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Writing the equivalent initializer is a superb idea. I added that in. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Upvote or not, those *are* good suggestions. So thanks anyway :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much! this information helped me ALOT! I started computer science in the University out of interest, It turned out to be very hard, but because people like yourself I keep going on and learn something new each time I encounter a problem, thank you!

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks! one more question - will scanning the data into inner struct variables better be done with malloc?

Comment: @YaroslavMiloslavsky - I don't see why one would need `malloc` here. There's no call to dynamic memory allocation.